# Where does Gdx search when i use Gdx.files.local(path)?

Tags: java, android, file, local, assets

I'm using libgdx for a game. I want to read/write text files to update highscores, very simple. 
I have three files already created placed in "$ANDROID-PROJECT/assets/data" , but Gdx seems to not find them when i use Gdx.files.local("data/file.txt"), but it does when i use Gdx.files.internal("data/file.txt"). Because i need to also write the file, i'm forced to use Gdx.files.local.

Can anyone tell me Where does Gdx search when i use Gdx.files.local(path) ? what path should i specify ?

**code:**

```
//for read
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("data/scoresCla.txt");

clasico = Float.parseFloat(file.readString());

//for write
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("data/scoresCla.txt");

file.writeString(String.valueOf(res), false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if anybody have this problem, i solved by changing Gdx.files.local for Gdx.files.external. This way the files are stored in the SD Card, it has the same functionality of R/W files as local but in the SD Card.